# Select records from 2 tables and ordering them

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables A and B with following records

```
--TABLE A--  
id        date          value  
1        09/01/2012    Reward  
2        09/01/2012    Purchase  
3        07/01/2012    Reward  
4        07/01/2012    Purchase

--TABLE B--  
id   id_from_a     date           value  
1       1         10/01/2012     Generated Rewrd   
2       3         08/01/2012     Generated Reward
```

Now I want the result to be like below

```
id        date          value  
1         10/01/2012    Generated Reward  
1         09/01/2012    Reward  
2         09/01/2012    Purchase  
3         08/01/2012    Generated Reward  
3         07/01/2012    Reward  
4         07/01/2012    Purchase
```

I know using `UNIONS` will merge these 2 tables but how do i order it like i have mentioned above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A UNION can have a single ORDER BY clause specified at the end which applies to the entire, combined result set.

```
SELECT id, date, value
    FROM table_A
UNION
SELECT id, date, value
    FROM table_B
ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

If you don't need the deduplicating feature of the UNION operation, a UNION ALL will yield better performance.

```
SELECT id, date, value
    FROM table_A
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date, value
    FROM table_B
ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

Comment: It is implied that id is ASC. That is, the default for ORDER BY is ASCending, so if you want descending, you specify DESC as Joe did.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need `id` from `table_a` and `id_from_a` from `table_b`. You can merely use `id` in the `ORDER BY` clause though:

```
SELECT 
 id, date, value
FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT
  id_from_a, date, value
FROM table_b
ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(SELECT id, date, value FROM Table_A
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date, value FROM Tabble_B)
ORDER BY id, date DESC
```

Make sure you use UNION ALL for safety's sake. UNION ALL is to UNION what SELECT DISTINCT is to SELECT... UNION ALL will display all instances of duplicated records instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

You can order the result of union, check the syntax below

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a;
```

Also look
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html